# "instagram graph api" business discovery does not return media url of reels

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm retrieving influencers data through business discovery and notice that some of the media url for reels are not being returned.

Out of 6 reels media data I've collected, media url only came with oldest one which was posted on April 24th. Second oldest one was posted May 11.

Media url for feed are all collected.

How would I be able to get media url for reels?

Code running are

```
def user_info(version, igUserId,access_token,username,fields):
    request_url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/{version}/{IgUserID}?fields=business_discovery.username({username}){{{fields}}}&access_token={access_token}"
    response = requests.get(request_url)
    return response.json()
result = user_info(version,IgUserID,accessToken,username,fields)
print(result["business_discovery"]["media"]["data"][0])
print(result["business_discovery"]["media"]["data"][1])
```

Responce are below. Showing first two in a list

```
{'id': 'firstID', 'like_count': 6904, 'comments_count': 42, 'timestamp': '2023-06-14T09:09:25+0000', 'username': 'username', 'media_product_type': 'REELS', 'media_type': 'VIDEO'}
{'id': 'secondID', 'like_count': 3691, 'comments_count': 28, 'timestamp': '2023-06-13T11:29:38+0000', 'username': 'username', 'media_product_type': 'FEED', 'media_type': 'CAROUSEL_ALBUM', 'media_url': 'mediaUrl'},
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what is missing from the response.

Comment: could you please suggest which Instagram API should I choose for search Instagram users and their data like instanavigation.com Should I choose graph API or basic display API? I am using Next.js

Comment: If your purpose was to collect data your choice will be Graph Api. If you want to collect data of account that not yours use Business Discovery in Graph Api. I'm using python but it should be same for Next.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined [in the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/):

> "The media_url field is omitted from responses if the media contains copyrighted material or has been flagged for a copyright violation. Examples of copyrighted material can include audio on reels."

Unfortunately, this is very often the case, as so many reels include copyrighted music. It appears the media_url is simply not available through APIs in these cases.